# php mysql duplicate primary key

Tags: php, mysql

i had build a table like this :

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE $singleton(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(ID),
sort_order INTEGER)";
```

when iam filling something in after 25 times there was no problem

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: 
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '26' for key 'PRIMARY'' in........
```

this seems me like a bug because i am not trying to manipulate the ID ..

what to do?

Comment: when i try wihtout $ it works fine. So just check it is replacing correctly or not. Or that particular table is already exist in DB.

Comment: Is `$singleton` a php variable in your code?

Comment: $singleton is just a trivial string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

primary key(column_name) is a table level option of create statement so mention it at last

```
CREATE TABLE $singleton(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,sort_order INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

or use the below query

```
CREATE TABLE $singleton(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,sort_order INTEGER)";
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the sytax is causing the error.

CREATE TABLE singleton
(
P_Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)
)